# Qual melhor forma para alinhar colunas do DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Qual a melhor forma de alinhar as colunas de um DataGridView, pois se colocado para alinhar pelo tamanho do nome da coluna é cortado as células que são maiores que o tamanho do nome da coluna, e quando colocado para alinhar pela célula e o tamanho da célula for menor que o cabeçado, o cabeçalho é cortado, estou começando a mexer com parte Windows Forms agora e tenho está dúvida, qual a melhor forma de apresentar os registros da Grid?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize esta extensão em seu código, ela ajeita o `datagridview`, e deixa as colunas "livres" se o usuário quiser redimensionar, e já formata as colunas que são decimais.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AjeitaDataGridView(this DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        //para deixar o tamanho "certo e editavel" o tamanho da coluna
        // all cells bloqueia o usuario a nao editar
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            int colw = dataGridView.Columns[i].Width;
            if (dataGridView.Columns[i].ValueType == typeof(Decimal))
            {
                dataGridView.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            }
            //
            dataGridView.Columns[i].Width = colw;
        }

        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
    }
}
```

e no seu código basta chamar..

```
this.datagridview1.AjeitaDataGridView();
```

Referência: [How do you automatically resize columns in a DataGridView control AND allow the user to resize the columns on that same grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049887/6163123)

Comment: Marco, só uma dúvida, porque você pega o tamanho da coluna, e depois seta novamente o tamanho da coluna? isso faz que ela fique renderizada?

Comment: Sei que parece idiota.. Achei um exemplo disto numa resposta no SO-en.. se eu achar depois, coloco a referencia aqui..mas isso faz com que quando  você `dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;` a coluna não volte para o valor de "antes", você pode fazer um teste.. comentando a linha `dataGridView.Columns[i].Width = colw;`, vai ver que não irá funcionar...

Comment: Coloquei a referência na resposta...

Answer (score 0):

eu utilizo:

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

As larguras da coluna são ajustadas para que o conteúdo de todas as células nas colunas, incluindo as células de cabeçalho, caiba nela.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx